# PyCharm не отображает вывод процентов выполнения mkvextract

Tags: python, pycharm

Вынимаю сабы из видео через mkvextract который обернул в subprocess с прочей обработкой вроде выбора трека который надо вынимать.
Вот такой командой:

```
subprocess.call('mkvextract tracks "{0}" {1}:"{2}"'.format(path_video, id_is, 
                 filename + '.' + sub_ext), shell=True)

# или для консоли без обертки выходит:
mkvextract tracks "way_to_mkv.mkv" 2:"way_to_ass.ass"
```

Если я запускаю эту команду в консоли, то, под строкой с сообщением о начале работы extract'а, будут отображаться проценты выполнения. В pycharm'е отображается пустая строка и в конце появится надпись про 100%.

Как чего поправить, чтобы проценты отображались корректно в окне Run pycharm'а?

Как это выглядит:

[image: Pycharm]
[image: Console]

Comment: Попробуй в соответствующей Run конфигурации (Run -> Edit Configurations ...) поставить галочку "Emulate terminal in output console".

Comment: Это оно, спасибо (я же помнил, что где то чего то такое видел... но гугл не помог). Напиши то же в виде ответа, галочку поставлю-закрою вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо включить опцию "Emulate terminal in output console" в Run конфигурации, которая используется для запуска скрипта (меню **Run | Edit Configurations ...**)

[image]